# How to map path to a directory other than the root directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

How will you do it if you need to map path to a directory other than the root directory in c# application.

What I tried is:

```
public ActionResult Search()
    {
        return File("C:/Users/Rehan/Desktop/Pro Collection/xyz.pdf", "pdf");
    }
```

but unfortunately no avail.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to archieve, in your example you already have the full Path to the document. So what kind of path do you exactly need?

Comment: You can not map the Path because the file is located outside your web page. So what do you want to do with the file?

Comment: @DenisThomas I want it display the file in the browser. Accessing a file outside my web application is the question I am trying to target.

Comment: @DenisThomas I have edited the code in question. Please have a look.

Comment: @DenisThomas Error I'm getting on the above code is `Could not find file 'C:\Users\Rehan\Desktop\Pro Collection\xyz.pdf`.

Comment: I tried this and it works. When you get this Exception I would suspect that your path is simply wrong. Have you checked in explorer if the pdf is really there and the path is correct?

Comment: @DenisThomas Yes path was not correct. Thanks for solving this mystery for me. Its working now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a FileResult

```
public FileResult Search()
    {
        return new FilePathResult("C:/Users/Rehan/Desktop/Pro Collection/xyz.pdf", "application/pdf");
    }
```

Comment: `Error: Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface System.Web.Mvc.FileResult`

Comment: sorry I was a bit to fast there , should be a filepathresult that you return